# Why can't I mark my question as answered on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, accepted-answer, answers-as-comments

I understand from reading several other questions how marking a question as answered should look - i.e. simply hitting the checkmark next to the best answer. I also understand, from reading, that there's a time delay before a question can be marked as answered, and that you must be logged in while looking at the main page for your question.

I am a new user. This is my first Stack Overflow question, and I have no reputation yet. My understanding is that it doesn't require reputation to mark an answer.

Here is exactly what I see while looking at [my question (posted, as of right now, 16 hours ago)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75935110/how-do-i-modify-rarebit-to-display-some-unique-html-text-on-every-page-in-additi) while logged in:

> [image: screenshot of question - there is no checkbox]

There is no checkmark visible. Why can't I mark it as answered? I'd like to give James reputation for his excellent solution.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's no checkmark visible because that's not an *answer*; it's a *comment*. That's why answers to a question should be posted [as answers, not as comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/answers-as-comments). Comments are [temporary things, meant to improve a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment), and will be deleted as soon as they've served their purpose. You should ask James (with a comment) to post that as an answer instead (and perhaps expand a bit if necessary - references to back up an answer never hurt).